# problem with running fyne setup tool on macos

Tags: go, fyne

I am just getting started with fyne GUI platform. I have installed fyne using the commands:

```
$ go get fyne.io/fyne/v2@latest
$ go get fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne@latest
```

Then the instruction [page](https://developer.fyne.io/started/) asks to test the setup using the [fyne setup tool](https://geoffrey-artefacts.fynelabs.com/github/andydotxyz/fyne-io/setup/latest/). As usual, on macos arbitrary downloaded executables are not allowed to run, so I had to download it through safari browser, and then give the permissions in the security page.

Now when I click on this downloaded app, I get the following error:

[image]

I also tried to run the app from the command line, and then I get a different error:

[image]

However, I do have go and fyne installed in my path:

```
$ which go ---> /usr/local/bin/go
$ which fyne ---> /Users/xxx/go/bin/fyne
$ go env GOPATH  ---> /Users/xxx/go
$ env $PATH ---> /usr/local/bin:/Users/xxx/go/bin: and other path items here
```

And golang is otherwise working perfectly fine on my macos. So whats the problem here, and how do I fix it?

But I decided to go ahead and try the next test command for fyne, and there also I ran into a very different error:

```
$ go run fyne.io/fyne/v2/cmd/fyne_demo@latest
gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option '-fobjc-arc'; did you mean '-fobjc-gc'?
```

And after that there were a zillion other error messages.

Is there any environment variable that I need to set before running fyne on macos?

NOTE: I am using go-1.20.4 darwin/amd64, installed with brew. And gcc version is: gcc (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0_3)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like everything should be working. Try running the setup app from the command line instead of double clicking it. Some type of user setting only apply to the terminal not to the desktop environment (and/or try logging out and back in).

Regarding the `gcc` error it may be that Brew didn’t install the best tool for the job. As you might see from the docs we recommend the XCode compiler instead (`xcode-select —-install` if you don’t have the command line tools installed already). More info at https://developer.fyne.io/started/.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to run the app from the command line. I tried that and I get a different error (I modified my question to include that error also).

Comment: On the gcc, are you suggesting that I remove gcc installation? xcode-select --install is already done on my mac.

Comment: Are there any hidden assumptions that I am miising out on? eg, I am using bash, is that ok? Any other environment variables to be set/unset, eg CC?

Comment: Yes uninstall gcc and use the recommended compiler that comes with Darwin. Nothing else is required and any shell should work. We have tested with bash, zsh and fish.

Comment: I need gcc for my other software, so that eliminates fyne and I will look at other gui platforms to use. Thanks for your advise.

Comment: You don’t have to uninstall the other gcc, but you could juggle paths instead. Bottom line is to compile native apps for Darwin/iOS you’ll need a compiler that understands the semantics. The XCode compiler does but it seems like your gcc doesn’t. 
I suspect if you install the XCode command line tools and ensure the source of your gcc is after it in the path then both would work.

Comment: You’ll probably find that most are the same. There is nothing in Fyne that specifically requires any version of the compiler - the reality is that to compile for a platform you’ll need the compiler for that platform.